# Search range of cells for specific text and change font format in cell next to it

Tags: excel, vba

Hello all this is my first question so I will try my best to format this best I can. 
I would like to write a VBA code where I search for a specific text (string) in column A:A. When it matches the condition then it has to go to the next cell right (Offset(0,1)) and generally change the format of font there and so on to the end of the range. There are not any blank cells in column A (range tested) and sometimes more than 5 thousand even more of rows.
To be a beginner in VBA programming I have any idea about how to process this problem and write my own code here, sorry. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: share your code.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeFont()

    Const colSource As Long = 1         ' Source Column Number
    Const colTarget As Long = 2         ' Target Column Number
    Const FR As Long = 2                ' First Row Number
    Const strCrit As String = "Karel"   ' Criteria String

    Dim cRng As Range                   ' Current Cell Range
    Dim LR As Long                      ' Last Row Number
    Dim i As Long                       ' Rows Counter

    ' Reset font formatting in Target Column starting from First Row to bottom.
    With Cells(FR, colTarget).Resize(Rows.Count - colTarget + 1).Font
        .Bold = False
        .ColorIndex = 0 ' xlNone doesn't work!?
    End With

    ' Calculate Last Row Number.
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, colSource).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = FR To LR
        ' Calculate Current Cell Range.
        Set cRng = Cells(i, colSource)
        ' Check value in Current Cell Range against Criteria String.
        If cRng.Value = strCrit Then
            ' If they're equal apply font formatting in cell to the right.
            With cRng.Offset(, 1).Font
                .Bold = True
                .ColorIndex = 3
            End With
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r As Range, v As Variant
    For Each r In Range("A:A")
        v = r.Value
        If v = "" Then Exit Sub
        If InStr(v, "treasure") > 0 Then r.Offset(0, 1).Font.Bold = True
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

If you know the range then, for example, replace:

```
Range("A:A")
```

with:

```
Range("A1:A100")
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks very easy. But how it should be when I do know the range, it means A1:Ax, where x is the last noblank cell.

Comment: Sorry ...I do not know...

Comment: @Karel568  see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Yes, but I do NOT know the range.

Comment: @Karel568  You don't need to know the range...the code automatically stops when it finds the first empty cell !!

Comment: Thanks a lot of all of you, I really appreciate your help. Karel